# weird iis request delays

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have such configuration: one master site and 5 node sites (on different machines) master site makes simultaneous requests to nodes (using HttpClient) and measures how long does it take each site to answer. Each node measures how long does it take to answer request. Now most of the time these measurements are very similar but sometimes (about 15% of time) master node measures much longer time it takes the node to answer while node says it has done it's request fast. Say node says it took 300 ms from action first instruction to the last (action in controller) and master says the overall request took 3000 ms. Why is that? I suspect this has something to do with iis (iis v 7.5 and 8.5)

**EDIT**
The problem was that HttpClient doesn't work well on Windows server 2008. Moving master to newer server solved it.

**EDIT2**

I was using HttpClient incorrectly, since only one instance should be around as described [here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: Is 3000ms combination of all 5 nodes? In other words, does master site wait data from all nodes to complete?

Comment: @Win Nodes are called in parallel from master, 3000ms is request from one node while others may be fast.

Comment: IIS can handle pretty heavy load; I don't think IIS is the bottle neck. Does 300ms include network latency from master to node and vice versa?

Comment: @Win yes 85% of time if node's action takes 300ms then entire request from master (including network latency) takes say 350 ms and then ocasionally 3000 ms or so